# Purpose of Legolas' affliation to the Elves

Tags: war-of-the-ring

**What is the purpose of Legolas' affliation to the Elven Nation?**

Each companion of The Fellowship has a nation shown on their card which indicates that **the character can activate that nation** by visiting a settlement of that nation.  Legolas is linked to the Elven Nation; however, **the Elves already begin the game activated,** seemingly making this pointless.

Is there any other significance to Legolas' ability to activate the Elves?  Can the Elven Nation somehow become inactive and need to be re-activated?  Are there event cards that make mention of a character's national affiliation in some other useful way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a nation cannot become inactive once it is active.
Legolas just has the nation symbol for thematic purposes. He is an Elf, so he has the Elven symbol.
This is consistent with the other Companions: Gimli has the Dwarven symbol, Boromir the Gondor symbol and Strider the North symbol. **But for game purposes Legolas' symbol is indeed pointless.**
Similarly, the Shadow characters also have a nation symbol, which are also pointless for game purposes.

However, the expansion, 'Lords of Middle Earth' makes him inconsistent with the others.
The expansion has alternate versions of the Companions who don't have a nation symbol. They can only activate their respective nation with an ability using an Action Die. But because the Elves start the game active, they did not remove the nation symbol from the new Legolas. It is still pointless for him to have it.